# Firestore data is not syncing when app is closed

Tags: ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I am using ionic 3 and cloud firestore.

I have enabled persistance data for offline capability.

The data is syncing when the app is open.

But the data is not syncing when the app is closed.

Any idea?

Comment: That sounds like the expected behavior to me. When the app is not actively being used, the OS typically turns off most of its resource consumption. If you want to maintain data sync while the app is closed, have a look at [Ionic background tasks](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/background-task/), or consider using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send messages to the app for important events. The latter is by far preferred, since it is likely to reduce battery and data consumption by the app while backgrounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like the expected behavior to me. When the app is not actively being used, the OS typically turns off most of its resource consumption.

If you want to maintain data sync while the app is closed, have a look at [Ionic background tasks](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/background-task/), or consider using [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/index) to send messages to the app for important events. The latter is by far preferred, since it is likely to reduce battery and data consumption by the app while backgrounded.